# Cant connect Android Wear Device via bluetooth

Tags: wear-os

I have USB debugging on and I am showing that the Target is connected I however am unable to connect the host.

When I run the below command on my PC I get output indicating that the command is not complete.

```
adb forward tcp:4444 localabstract:/adb-hub; adb connect localhost:4444
```

Output:

```
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Android Studio>adb forward
tcp: 4444 localabstract:/adb-hub;adb connect localhost:4444
Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.31

 -a                            - directs adb to listen on all interfaces for a c
onnection
 -d                            - directs command to the only connected USB devic
e
                                 returns an error if more than one USB device is
 present.
 -e                            - directs command to the only running emulator.
                                 returns an error if more than one emulator is r
unning.
 -s <specific device>          - directs command to the device or emulator with
the given
                                 serial number or qualifier. Overrides ANDROID_S
ERIAL
                                 environment variable.
 -p <product name or path>     - simple product name like 'sooner', or
                                 a relative/absolute path to a product
                                 out directory like 'out/target/product/sooner'.

                                 If -p is not specified, the ANDROID_PRODUCT_OUT

                                 environment variable is used, which must
                                 be an absolute path.
 -H                            - Name of adb server host (default: localhost)
 -P                            - Port of adb server (default: 5037)
 devices [-l]                  - list all connected devices
                                 ('-l' will also list device qualifiers)
 connect <host>[:<port>]       - connect to a device via TCP/IP
                                 Port 5555 is used by default if no port number
is specified.
 disconnect [<host>[:<port>]]  - disconnect from a TCP/IP device.
                                 Port 5555 is used by default if no port number
is specified.
                                 Using this command with no additional arguments

                                 will disconnect from all connected TCP/IP devic
es.

device commands:
  adb push <local> <remote>    - copy file/dir to device
  adb pull <remote> [<local>]  - copy file/dir from device
  adb sync [ <directory> ]     - copy host->device only if changed
                                 (-l means list but don't copy)
                                 (see 'adb help all')
  adb shell                    - run remote shell interactively
  adb shell <command>          - run remote shell command
  adb emu <command>            - run emulator console command
  adb logcat [ <filter-spec> ] - View device log
  adb forward --list           - list all forward socket connections.
                                 the format is a list of lines with the followin
g format:
                                    <serial> " " <local> " " <remote> "\n"
  adb forward <local> <remote> - forward socket connections
                                 forward specs are one of:
                                   tcp:<port>
                                   localabstract:<unix domain socket name>
                                   localreserved:<unix domain socket name>
                                   localfilesystem:<unix domain socket name>
                                   dev:<character device name>
                                   jdwp:<process pid> (remote only)
  adb forward --no-rebind <local> <remote>
                               - same as 'adb forward <local> <remote>' but fail
s
                                 if <local> is already forwarded
  adb forward --remove <local> - remove a specific forward socket connection
  adb forward --remove-all     - remove all forward socket connections
  adb jdwp                     - list PIDs of processes hosting a JDWP transport

  adb install [-l] [-r] [-s] [--algo <algorithm name> --key <hex-encoded key> --
iv <hex-encoded iv>] <file>
                               - push this package file to the device and instal
l it
                                 ('-l' means forward-lock the app)
                                 ('-r' means reinstall the app, keeping its data
)
                                 ('-s' means install on SD card instead of inter
nal storage)
                                 ('--algo', '--key', and '--iv' mean the file is
 encrypted already)
  adb uninstall [-k] <package> - remove this app package from the device
                                 ('-k' means keep the data and cache directories
)
  adb bugreport                - return all information from the device
                                 that should be included in a bug report.

  adb backup [-f <file>] [-apk|-noapk] [-obb|-noobb] [-shared|-noshared] [-all]
[-system|-nosystem] [<packages...>]
                               - write an archive of the device's data to <file>
.
                                 If no -f option is supplied then the data is wr
itten
                                 to "backup.ab" in the current directory.
                                 (-apk|-noapk enable/disable backup of the .apks
 themselves
                                    in the archive; the default is noapk.)
                                 (-obb|-noobb enable/disable backup of any insta
lled apk expansion
                                    (aka .obb) files associated with each applic
ation; the default
                                    is noobb.)
                                 (-shared|-noshared enable/disable backup of the
 device's
                                    shared storage / SD card contents; the defau
lt is noshared.)
                                 (-all means to back up all installed applicatio
ns)
                                 (-system|-nosystem toggles whether -all automat
ically includes
                                    system applications; the default is to inclu
de system apps)
                                 (<packages...> is the list of applications to b
e backed up.  If
                                    the -all or -shared flags are passed, then t
he package
                                    list is optional.  Applications explicitly g
iven on the
                                    command line will be included even if -nosys
tem would
                                    ordinarily cause them to be omitted.)

  adb restore <file>           - restore device contents from the <file> backup
archive

  adb help                     - show this help message
  adb version                  - show version num

scripting:
  adb wait-for-device          - block until device is online
  adb start-server             - ensure that there is a server running
  adb kill-server              - kill the server if it is running
  adb get-state                - prints: offline | bootloader | device
  adb get-serialno             - prints: <serial-number>
  adb get-devpath              - prints: <device-path>
  adb status-window            - continuously print device status for a specifie
d device
  adb remount                  - remounts the /system partition on the device re
ad-write
  adb reboot [bootloader|recovery] - reboots the device, optionally into the boo
tloader or recovery program
  adb reboot-bootloader        - reboots the device into the bootloader
  adb root                     - restarts the adbd daemon with root permissions
  adb usb                      - restarts the adbd daemon listening on USB
  adb tcpip <port>             - restarts the adbd daemon listening on TCP on th
e specified port
networking:
  adb ppp <tty> [parameters]   - Run PPP over USB.
 Note: you should not automatically start a PPP connection.
 <tty> refers to the tty for PPP stream. Eg. dev:/dev/omap_csmi_tty1
 [parameters] - Eg. defaultroute debug dump local notty usepeerdns

adb sync notes: adb sync [ <directory> ]
  <localdir> can be interpreted in several ways:

  - If <directory> is not specified, both /system and /data partitions will be u
pdated.

  - If it is "system" or "data", only the corresponding partition
    is updated.

environmental variables:
  ADB_TRACE                    - Print debug information. A comma separated list
 of the following values
                                 1 or all, adb, sockets, packets, rwx, usb, sync
, sysdeps, transport, jdwp
  ANDROID_SERIAL               - The serial number to connect to. -s takes prior
ity over this if given.
  ANDROID_LOG_TAGS             - When used with the logcat option, only these de
bug tags are printed.
```

Comment: please do @UhrArt a favor and click the green check next to his answer to mark it as such.

Answer (score 15):

For your information, I finally solved the same problem by replacing port 4444 by 5601.

The 2 calls are:

```
adb forward tcp:5601 localabstract:/adb-hub
```

and

```
adb connect localhost:5601
```

(My Android Wear device is a LG G Watch and my Android tablet is an Asus Nexus 7)

Comment: Should've accepted UhrArt's answer above, as it is the same information.

Comment: I get an error: `unable to connect to localhost:5601: Connection refused`

Comment: Same problem here with connection refused

Answer (score 11):

This is easy to solve:

I had the same problem.
Just devide this into two calls.

First enter:

```
adb forward tcp:4444 localabstract:/adb-hub
```

hit Enter and after that:

```
adb connect localhost:4444
```

Enter and it should connect. If not try first to start the "adb start-server"

Comment: also make sure bluetooth debugging is enabled on the WATCH not just the Phone. Go to Settings->About and tap Build 5 times to put the Watch in developer mode.

Comment: Works for connecting, but cannot upload any APKs.  Just stuck on `Uploading file to: /data/local/tmp/com.example.android.google.wearable.app`

Comment: unable to connect to localhost:4444: Connection refused

Answer (score 5):

try Ip address instead of localhost when connecting

adb forward tcp:4444 localabstract:/adb-hub

adb connect 127.0.0.1:4444

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem as well. After running the above commands in the Command Line, I solved it by activating the Developer Options on my Moto 360 (pressing the build number repeatedly in the settings like the phone). Enabling the ADB and Bluetooth Debugging on the watch and unpairing my watch with my phone.

After I did all these steps my computer finally sent the RSA permissions key for my Android Wear device through my phone.

Comment: Why would you unpair your watch with the phone?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Just trying a couple different things to have the phone's Bluetooth connection reset. Unpairing and pairing the smart watch was one of the things I tried.

Answer (score 2):

The Complete solution for this issue..

```
 1. Open Your-sdk-path in Explorer.  
 2. Open platform-tools.
 3. Shift + Rightclick then select Open command window here.
 4. adb forward tcp:4444 localabstract:/adb-hub
    adb connect localhost:4444 (For Real Device).

 5. adb -d forward tcp:5601 tcp:5601 (for EMulator).
   Then after connect with emulator in Android wear companion app.
```

Before Doing step 4 please ensure that debugging over bluetooth is enabled in developer option.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Your-sdk-path in Explorer, and then "platform-tools", where it should be your adb.exe , in my case this is ( *C:\Users\YourUser\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools* )
2. Shift + Rightclick then select Open command window here.
3. paste "*adb forward tcp:4444 localabstract:/adb-hub*"
4. And then paste  "*adb connect 127.0.0.1:4444*" (**do not put *localhost* it is giving problems).**
5. you can check with "adb devices"

Answer (score 0):

I also had issue adb debugging over bluethooth:
`Debugging over Bluetooth` was always `Off` for me. Apparently I had to **choose a debugging wearable device** here:

`Android Wear -> Settings (gear icon) -> Debugging over Bluetooth -> Device to Debug`

Then all other comments are helpful too.

Answer (score 0):

Tried all of the above, nothing helped.
The one thing that helped me was to restart the phone...