# Cannot connect to Android Wear Device via bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, connection, wear-os, android-bluetooth

I want to connect my Samsung Gear Live with my Samsung Smartphone Device and am trying to follow the given[instruction](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/bt-debugging.html). Also kept searching on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25107791/cant-connect-android-wear-device-via-bluetooth) with similar problems, but it seems that it is something else.

So this what happens when I am using the terminal to connect:

```
Denjos-MacBook-Pro-2:platform-tools Denjo$ cd /Users/Denjo/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
Denjos-MacBook-Pro-2:platform-tools Denjo$ ./adb forward tcp:4444 localabstract:/adb-hub
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
error: device not found
error: device not found
Denjos-MacBook-Pro-2:platform-tools Denjo$
```

What am I probably doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it this way, that I changed the USB-cord.